# req.body.username coming as undefined after making post request to my MEAN app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I make make post request to my MEAN app I am getting req.body.username as undefined upon debugging.
 Below is my route file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var auth = require('../auth');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.setPassword(req.body.password);
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.json({ token: user.to() })
    });
});

router.post('/users/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.user.email){
    return res.status(422).json({errors: {email: "can't be blank"}});
  }

  if(!req.body.user.password){
    return res.status(422).json({errors: {password: "can't be blank"}});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      user.token = user.generateJWT();
      return res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON()});
    } else {
      return res.status(422).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/user', auth.required, function(req, res, next){
  User.findById(req.payload.id).then(function(user){
    if(!user){ return res.sendStatus(401); }

    return res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON()});
  }).catch(next);
});  

router.put('/user', auth.required, function(req, res, next){
    User.findById(req.payload.id).then(function(user){
      if(!user){ return res.sendStatus(401); }

      if(typeof req.body.user.username !== 'undefined'){
        user.username = req.body.user.username;
      }
      if(typeof req.body.user.email !== 'undefined'){
        user.email = req.body.user.email;
      }
      if(typeof req.body.user.bio !== 'undefined'){
        user.bio = req.body.user.bio;
      }
      if(typeof req.body.user.image !== 'undefined'){
        user.image = req.body.user.image;
      }
      if(typeof req.body.user.password !== 'undefined'){
        user.setPassword(req.body.user.password);
      }

      return user.save().then(function(){
        return res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON()});
      });
    }).catch(next);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

And below is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/conduit');
require('./models/Users');
require('./routes/index');
require('./routes/auth');
var users=require('./routes/api/users');
require('./routes/api/index');




app.use('/', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have my trying to find a solution but so far have been unfortunately unable to do so. I tried a couple of suggestions like change the order of bodyParser middleware and all but so far have been unable to do so.

Comment: Can you post your HTML form for completeness sake?

Comment: Can you post the request you are making to your '/users' route?